# Handling application force quit in Swift for macOS applications

Tags: swift, macos, sigkill

"I'm currently developing a macOS application using Swift and I need to perform a certain action (in my case, remapping a key) when the application is terminated. I am able to handle the situation where the application is quit normally using the `applicationWillTerminate(_:)` method in the `AppDelegate`, but this doesn't get called when the application is force quit, such as through the Activity Monitor.

I understand that when an application is forcibly quit, the operating system sends it a `SIGKILL` signal that it cannot ignore or handle, so it immediately stops without executing any further code. However, is there any workaround or alternative approach that would allow me to handle this scenario or achieve a similar effect? I would appreciate any suggestions or insights."

Answer (score 3):

You can run a separate process that monitors the first, and detects when it stops running. During normal shutdown, the main program can terminate the monitor. This can also be circular, so that the main program watches the monitor and relaunches it if the monitor is killed. Or you can use a [Launch Daemon](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) to automatically re-launch the monitor if needed.